How do I center the submenu text or move the submenu item on Elementor so that everything aligns?
I'm using Elementor and having trouble aligning the text and the items properly, so I get this:

I've tried using various custom CSS codes I've found on here and Reddit, but nothing seems to be working. I'd like the left padding to be smaller. What can I try next?

To center the text in the drop-down menu, add a class to your Elementor menu (the below example uses the drop-down-menu class) and use the below CSS code:
.drop-down-menu {
  /* To ensure the padding on the left and right is the same */
  padding-left: 0px; /* Any value followed by a unit can be used here, 0px is just an example */
  padding-right: 0px;
  /* To center the text horizontally */
  text-align: center;
}

